# Интерфейс стал плыть на мобильных устройствах при обновлении Unity2018 и SDK 27

Tags: unity3d

Обновил юнити и сдк до 27 версии.
Когда делаю билд под андроид, то весь UI начинает плыть.

> Вот как выглядит UI в Unity - http://joxi.ru/52a89wehE9KyKm
>   Как выглядит на моб устройствах - http://joxi.ru/5md0VDnI34El9m

Причем раньше такой проблемы не было (до обновления юнити и сдк).
Проблема в юнити? в Сдк? или в новом юнити нужно что-то настроить чтобы такой фигни не было?

Comment: На вид похоже что изображения не кратны степени 2.

Comment: Можешь подробнее объяснить?

Comment: попробовал создать новый проект, совершенно пустой, добавил пару кнопок - интерфейс нормальный. создал еще один проект, залил туда свои префабы - интерфейс сломался. это происходит только уже на самом устройстве, в редакторе все нормально

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**

### Исправил ошибку.

**
Ошибка была из-за того что у камеры в параметре `Clear Flags` было установлено значение `don't clear` , я поменял на значение: `Solid Color` и баг исчез.

Comment: Так если вы буфер конечного изображения не почистили - это ваша ошибка, а не баг Unity :)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте выбрать ваши изображения в проекте и выбрать им режим без сжатия. Возможно, при реимпорте в новый юнити сжатие выставило на среднее автоматически. Сталкивался уже с таким.

Comment: не получилось :( всё также